# PyQGIS - add ArcGIS Feature Service layer to QGIS including a query

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, arcgis-server, feature-service

I want to add an ArcGIS feature layer to QGIS using PyQGIS, with a query.

If I just want to add the layer, I can use the following code. Though I would point out that the *arcgisfeatureserver* provider is not documented at https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html. The server is a public one so you should be able to easily replicate this:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setParam('crs', 'EPSG:3857')
uri.setParam('url', 'https://portal.spatial.nsw.gov.au/server/rest/services/NSW_Features_of_Interest_Category/MapServer/2')
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "Test Layer" , 'arcgisfeatureserver')
if layer.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
else:
    print('Invalid layer: failed to add layer')
```

I now want to add a basic query to the PyQGIS code, to avoid retrieving all records - for example:

```
where classsubtype = 12
```

To query the server directly, you can modify the REST URL eg:

```
https://portal.spatial.nsw.gov.au/server/rest/services/NSW_Features_of_Interest_Category/MapServer/2/query?where=classsubtype+%3D+12&f=json
```

However, if I try to do this by modifying the *url* parameter in PyQGIS, I get an invalid layer:

```
uri.setParam('url', 'https://portal.spatial.nsw.gov.au/server/rest/services/NSW_Features_of_Interest_Category/MapServer/2/query?where=classsubtype+%3D+12&f=json')
```

Is it possible to use queries or filters on ArcGIS feature layers via PyQGIS?

I'd note that I also cannot see how to do querying or filtering of ArcGIS feature layers, even if I try to add them via the GUI - Add Layer->Add ArcGIS REST Server Layer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reason [ArcGIS Feature Server documentation · Issue #6317 · qgis/QGIS-Documentation · GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/6317) was logged a few years ago, the documentation on this specific topic is quite poor.

One approach I have found that works, since figuring out the URI parameters is so elusive, is to create the layer without any filtering, and then set a filter using [setSubsetString - Class: QgsVectorLayer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.setSubsetString) before adding it to the project.

```py
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setParam('crs', 'EPSG:3857')
uri.setParam('url', 'https://portal.spatial.nsw.gov.au/server/rest/services/NSW_Features_of_Interest_Category/MapServer/2')
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "Test Layer" , 'arcgisfeatureserver')
layer.setSubsetString('"classsubtype" = 12')
if layer.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
else:
    print('Invalid layer: failed to add layer')
```

**UPDATE:**

After some tinkering, it appears `QgsDataSourceUri.setParam()` sets the parameters in alphabetical order, and that having a SQL statement before the URL causes the layer data source to become invalid, at least with `arcgisfeatureserver`.  The related "set" functions of `QgsDataSourceUri` do put the parameters in the correct order, so using them results in the following code that works:

```py
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setParam('url', 'https://portal.spatial.nsw.gov.au/server/rest/services/NSW_Features_of_Interest_Category/MapServer/2')
uri.setSrid('EPSG:3857')
uri.setSql('"classsubtype" = 12')
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "Test Layer" , 'arcgisfeatureserver')
if layer.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
else:
    print('Invalid layer: failed to add layer')
```

Comment: Thanks - however I tried both of the above code snippets, and while they did result in valid layers, they didn't actually implement the filtering. They both returned ~919k records, which is the whole dataset. If "classsubtype = 12" was correctly filtering, it should return just 205 records.

Comment: I just tested the second code block again, and it creates a layer with 205 features, so I am not sure why it isn't working on your end.  I am using QGIS 3.28 and testing in the Python Console of an open QGIS session.

Comment: You're right - I had tested it on QGIS 3.22 and 3.26, but it looks like that feature was added in 3.28! https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog328/index.html#feature-add-subset-string-filter-support-for-arcgis-rest-layers

Answer (score 0):

While it does not exactly answer the question (because it is not adding the ArcGIS layer directly), the following approach may be useful for some people.

The code

- builds up the ArcGIS Feature Server query string manually, and adds it to the layer base URL
- uses ogr2ogr via a command window to create a new (GeoPackage) layer, using the URL
- loads the resulting layer into QGIS.

This approach could be extended to include other fields not currently supported by the QgsDataSourceUri for ArcGIS Feature Server requests.

```
import urllib.parse, subprocess

params = {}
params['project_crs_authid'] = 'EPSG:4326'
params['temp_folder'] = 'C:/Windows/Temp/'

layerParams = {
    "layerName": "beacon",
    "url": "https://portal.spatial.nsw.gov.au/server/rest/services/NSW_Features_of_Interest_Category/MapServer/2",
    "where": "classsubtype = 12",
}

arcGisParams = {
    "where": layerParams['where'],
    "outfields":"*",
    "f":"json"
}

# Build query string component of URL
queryStr='?'
for key, value in arcGisParams.items():
    queryStr += key
    queryStr += '='
    queryStr += urllib.parse.quote(value)
    queryStr += '&'

if len(arcGisParams) > 0:
    queryStr = queryStr.rstrip('&')
else:
    queryStr = ''

cmd = 'ogr2ogr -f GPKG '+params['temp_folder']+layerParams['layerName']+'.gpkg "'+layerParams['url']+'/query'+queryStr+'" -t_srs '+params['project_crs_authid']
subprocess.run (cmd)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(params['temp_folder']+layerParams['layerName']+'.gpkg', 'Test Layer', 'ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```